# Unable to install Pybinding package

Tags: python, physics

I am trying to install the pybinding package on my computer but when I try to `pip install pybinding` the following error pops up:

```
        File "C:\Users\angel\anaconda3\Lib\subprocess.py", line 413, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\angel\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-z9vxo_z4\\pybinding_4851178650bd40a9b084b3a2746cd869', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\angel\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-z9vxo_z4\\pybinding_4851178650bd40a9b084b3a2746cd869\\build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\Users\\angel\\anaconda3\\python.exe', '-DPB_WERROR=OFF', '-DPB_TESTS=OFF', '-DPB_NATIVE_SIMD=ON', '-DPB_MKL=OFF', '-DPB_CUDA=OFF', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\angel\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-z9vxo_z4\\pybinding_4851178650bd40a9b084b3a2746cd869\\build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pybinding
  Running setup.py clean for pybinding
Failed to build pybinding
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pybinding, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I am running on Windows 11, Anaconda as my environment and with all the prerequisite packages installed.

Comment: You would need to show the rest of the log just above that.

Comment: ... and more. I'm sure there's more output before that.

Comment: That is still missing all of the install log. Anyway, `pybinding` hasn't been updated in 3 years, chances are it may be hard to install on new Pythons.

Comment: Sorry the output is very long and I can't copy all of it here

Comment: Well, then I can't help you. If it's SO preventing you from pasting it here, you can try e.g. https://pastebin.run/